# URL Parameter key with space is converting into underscore

Tags: php

I am using core php.
i am trying to print the query string, both key and values.
but the keys with space is getting converting into underscore.

this is my simple php code

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

and the URL i am hitting - http://localhost/user.php?A%20String=wqe%20qwe

result - Array( [A_String] => wqe qwe)

In the result **A String** is converting into the **A_String**, value is showing the space correctly but key is not.
Is there any solution to this since i have parameters with underscore also ?

Comment: _"Is there any solution to this"_ - probably no other than to get the original query string out of $_SERVER, and then parsing it yourself. (You won't be able to use built-in functionality like `parse_str` - because that would also replace the space with an underscore again.)

Comment: If builtin parser doesn't match your needs, you'll have to [build your own](https://3v4l.org/EIubl#v8.2.5).